# Root of unity belongs to Z/qZ. How?

Tags: roots-of-unity, primitive-roots, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

EDIT: Really sorry for not posting this initially.. maybe it's easier to understand now. [Source](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/099.pdf), page 6.

[image: This is the actual full text]

I've stubled upon a statement similar to this:

"Let $m,q$ be two integers such that $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ contains a primitive $m$-th root of unity and denote one such primitive $m$-th root by $\zeta$. Recall that the $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial splits into linear terms modulo $q$, $\Phi_n(X)=\displaystyle\prod_{i\in (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*}(X-\zeta^i) \mod q$. "

I'd like some help understanding according to what definition we can say that a primitive root of unity (except for $\pm 1$ for $m=1$ and $2$) can be said to "belong" to $Z_q$. It's clear for me that the $Z_q$ in question is not the usual $Z_q$. Also, I'd appreciate a name of/link to a result that presents that factorization modulo $q$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $m=2$, $q=15$, and $\zeta = 4$.

Then (the class of) $\zeta$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity of $\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$, because it satisfies the definition ([wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Root_of_unity&oldid=846757455#General_definition)):

- It is an $m$-th root of unity: $\zeta^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 15$
- It is not a $k$-th root of unity for any $1 \leq k < m$: $\zeta^1 \equiv 4 \bmod 15$

Note, however, that the quoted passage is wrong, since in this case:

- $\Phi_m(X) = X + 1$
- $ (X - \zeta^1) = X - 4$

and these polynomials are not equivalent modulo $q$.

If you additionally require that $q$ be prime, the quoted passage is true. In this case the factorization is "obvious" in this case, since $\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$ is a field and the $\zeta^i$ are distinct roots of $\Phi_m(X)$.

If I recall correctly, another way for the quoted passage to be true without assuming $q$ is prime is if $\zeta$ is chosen to be one of the roots (in $\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$) of $\Phi_m(X)$.

Comment: Whoa! I apologize, but I do not understand how a non-integer (not even real) like that $\zeta$ can be $\equiv$ to 4 mod 15. That's probably why I don't understand how a root of unity can be part of $Z_q$. Could you shed some light on this, please :D?

Comment: @PhantomR: $\zeta = 4$, so $\zeta \equiv 4$ because $4 \equiv 4$.

Comment: @PhantomR I've included the definition of "primitive root of unity"

Comment: Thank you for your help. Am I missing out on something? Aren't these the complex roots of unity (like the Wikipedia article you mentioned says they usually are)? How can it be equal to $4$? Also, you mentioned the class of $\zeta$ ; I'd like to ask with respect to which binary relationship? I'm really sorry, I may be lacking a lot of basic knowledge in this domain.

Comment: It's not 100% clear that the cyclotomic polynomial of the question is the standard cyclotomic polynomial over the integers - although if the source of the quote is using it to mean the minimal polynomial of the primitive roots then it runs into a different problem.

Comment: @PhantomR: The Wikipedia article says when the ring is not specified, the complex numbers are implicitly assumed. Your problem specifies a ring: $\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$. So when we talk about primitive roots of unity in $\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$, we don't mean primitive roots of unity of $\mathbb{C}$. Also, I'm following the usual practice of denoting an element of $\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$ by specifying an integer representing an equivalence class. If you write elements of this ring as cosets, when I write $4$ I mean $4 + q \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you both! I've updated the original post with a picture to the full text before the statement I mentioned. I apologize for not doing so in the first place..

Comment: I can't figure out the ring meant in this case..

Comment: @PhantomR: It's the ring of integers modulo $q$.

Comment: Wow... thank you! I wasn't used to anything else being called 'root of unity' except for complex numbers.. A question regarding your answer: you wrote "If I recall correctly, another way for the quoted passage to be true without assuming q is prime is if ζ is chosen to be one of the roots (in Z/qZ) of Φm(X)." .. isn't that precisely what $\zeta$ is in my original post, so the statement I quoted is actually true?

Comment: I'd also like to ask, regarding my problem: how is the $\mathbb{A}$ mentioned in the picture the 'ring of integers of the $m$th cyclotomic number field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$'? Hopefully I'm not shadowing @Blacksmith's post above and you still notice that as well :).

Comment: @PhantomR Well maybe I can answer your question actually: it is known that for every cyclotomic field $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)$ its ring of integers is equal to $\mathbb Z[\zeta_m]$. Does it answer to your question?

Comment: And moreover recalling the definition of $\Phi_m(X)$ you can really show that $\mathbb Z[\zeta_m]\simeq \mathbb Z[X]/\Phi_m(X)$ but maybe to see this you need to have a small background in ring theory (especially quotient rings)

Comment: Oh, so it's an isomorphism equality, not a 'true' equality :). I can understand if it's like that, although I cannot write a proof :). Thank you!!!

Comment: yes exactly, even if keep on mind that very often in algebraic contexts if two objects are isomorphic then they are considered basically the same (since an isomorphism preserves all the "important" properties). This is why it usually happens that people write $=$ instead of $\simeq$.